# Create dynamic fields parameters using json array

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following script to Export a Table to Excel and to export data-table we have to provide fields name(Name, Description) and type etc. But in my case I have to pass fields name dynamically. It mean I have JSON array which need to iterate for fileds.

http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/table-export-to-excel

```
var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
                    data: ".exportTable",
                    schema: {
                        type: "table",
                        fields: {
                            Title: {type: String},
                            Description: {type: String},
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I tried as below and i know it is not right way but it is better to understand to you what i need

```
var fieldarray = <?php echo json_encode($meta_list); ?>;   

var dataSource = shield.DataSource.create({
                    data: ".exportTable",
                    schema: {
                        type: "table",
                        fields: {
                            $.each(fieldarray, function (index, value) {
                            value.label: {type: String},

                          });
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Maybe look at bracket notation? `[]`.

Comment: @brso05: thanks for the reply. but $.each is not accpted inside fields:{} is there other way?